# Knockout Binding/Parsing of Dates not on ViewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to add a new binding to knockout that creates a date selector, with a min and max value in the parameters on construct. However I cannot figure out how to format the dates for knockout to successfully parse them.

```
date: { Value: CurrentDate, MinDate: new Date('01/01/1900 00:00:00'), MaxDate: new Date('31/12/2099 00:00:00') }
```

This does not work.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to parse bindings.
date: { Value: CurrentDate, MinDate: new Date('01/01/1900 00:00:00'), MaxDate: new Date('31/12/2099 00:00:00') }
Message: Object #<observable> has no method 'getFullYear'

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<observable> has no method 'indexOf'
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Should I just pass in a string and construct the date in the date selector method?

Edit2: Custom binding is kind of like this.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var parameters = valueAccessor();
        var date = $(element).kendoDatePicker({
            // Use parameters to populate options
            value: parameters.Value(),
            min: parameters.MinDate,
            max: parameters.MaxDate
        });
    }
};
```

<del>However I don't think it is important as the exception occurs before this code is reached.</del>

Edit3: Nevermind it seems knockout turns the Dates into observables, and then it throws the error when I try to treat them as Dates.

Comment: Can you please post your custom `date` binding? Porbably a `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` call is missing...

Comment: Done. I don't think its relevant thought as the code is never reached. Exception happens on parsing of bindings.